# SQL how to get data with out including it in the group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table that has 3 columns in it. Date, Truck_id, Location. The table holds the data of what location each truck was in on each date and only gets a record added when a truck moves from one location to another. I am trying to write a query that will pull only the newest date for each tractor and then getting its location. But when I attempt to write this it forces me to either group by location or not get the location. What is the best way to go about this?

### DATE       | Truck_id | Location

03/02/2017 | 3489     | MO

02/15/2017 | 1478     | IL

02/02/2017 | 3489     | TX

03/01/2017 | 3911     | NC

03/13/2017 | 3489     | TX

01/12/2017 | 3911     | TX

example data.

SQL i attempted

```
   SELECT
    MAX(date),
    tractor_id,
    location
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    tractor_id,
    location
```

I was hoping it would show

03/13/2017 | 3489 | TX

02/15/2017 | 1478 | IL

03/01/2017 | 3911 | NC

But instead I get

03/02/2017 | 3489 | MO

02/15/2017 | 1478 | IL

03/13/2017 | 3489 | TX

03/01/2017 | 3911 | NC

01/12/2017 | 3911 | TX

I understand why it is working like this but I don't understand how to work around it.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: Updated with example data and my SQL I originally tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT  t1.Truck_Id,
        t2.Max_Date,
        t1.Location
FROM YourTable t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Truck_Id, MAX(Date) as Max_Date
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY Truck_Id) t2
    ON t1.Truck_Id = t2.Truck_Id
    AND t1.Date = t2.Max_Date
;
```